# Error because of maven dependency while using apache solr 6.1.0

Tags: java, maven, solr, pom.xml

Shows the error in maven project, on below line

> import org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrServer;

[image]

I have already added dependency, like

[image]

Then also it shows error.
Can anyone please suggest me is there any other dependency required to add here?

Answer (score 1):

This may be because `org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrServer` is removed in **solrj 6.1.0** as it was a deprecated class in previous versions. You should use `org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient` instead.

Please refer to [solrj java documentation](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/6_1_0/solr-solrj/index.html) to construct the HttpSolrClient. You should probably use `org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient.Builder` as shown below:

```
HttpSolrClient solrClient=new HttpSolrClient.Builder("http://my-solr-server:8983/solr").build();
```